# Python pandas: how to return 0 as value when calculating the mean of an empty data frame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am currently getting this error `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` when my formula try to get the mean of an empty dataframe. How can I **return 0** when the function is calculating the mean of an empty dataframe?

This is the dataframe:
[image]

This is the formula that I try to run:

```
df_percentage = round(df['Whole Day Percentage'].mean()*100)
```

This is the error that I get:
[image]

`df['Whole Day Percentage'].mean()` is returning `nan` currently but I want it to return 0 instead.

Comment: Using numpy would be better

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.empty`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) to check whether the dataframe is empty or not:

```
In [165]: df_percentage = round(df['Whole Day Percentage'].mean()*100) if not df.empty else 0

In [166]: df_percentage
Out[166]: 0
```

**OR:**

```
In [162]: def calc_mean(df):
     ...:     if df.empty:
     ...:         return 0
     ...:     return round(df['Whole Day Percentage'].mean()*100)
     ...: 

In [163]: calc_mean(df)
Out[163]: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df_percentage = round(np.nan_to_num(df['Whole Day Percentage'].mean()*100))
```

---

**df_percentage:**

```
0
```

---

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried your method but I get 0.0 instead of 0

Comment: which pandas version are you using? round will give you 0 only

Comment: I currently using pandas version 0.25.1

Comment: `round(0.00)` --> `0` I don't know why you are getting `0.0`